# Windows Forms C# - Making a button react differently depending on record shown

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Newbie here.
I am trying to create an app for a local library and was hoping to be able to have the synopsis of the book show up when you click on the synopsis button. I would like it to show different information depending on which record is being shown. Is this something that is possible to do?
Thank you community!
Megan

Library App User Interface:
[image]

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: How is the app currently changing records? What is the mechanism behind the "previous" and "next" buttons?

Comment: High level, see [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for windows desktop application which should be helpful yet may have you rethink what you have done so far depending on how data is read.

Comment: Where is your data going to be retrieved from?  a database? Can I see your schema?